# how to call a form from a second application and performing actions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have an app running on localhost:port1. On this app, there is a button which when clicked, opens up a modal dialog which has form with **First name**, **Last name** and a **close** and **submit button**. I have another app running on localhost:port2. I have a button which when clicked, opens up a modal dialog. withing this dialog in app2, I have an iframe which I will like to have the form from localhost:port1 and to also be able to perform the same action as if i was doing in it from the first app.

Currently I am getting the form in the iframe using jquery ajax but however, i am not able to perform any action because non of the buttons work. Below is the jquery code in my second app which gets the form from app1.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('https://localhost:port1/').then(function (html) {
            // Success response
            var $mainbar = $(html).find('#InsertDialog');
            $("#iframe").append('<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>');

            setTimeout(function () {
                var iframeBody = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");

                iframeBody.append($mainbar);
            },
                333
            );
        }, function () {
            // Error response
            document.write('Access denied');
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my second app, i have the following page,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" id="openModal">Open dialog</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" style="background: bisque">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content" style="height: 90%; width: 100%">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe" style="overflow: hidden; height: 80%; width: 90%; border: none;" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
                </div>
                @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="closeMyIframe">close</button>*@
                <div class="modal-footer" style="background: bisque">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="reload">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am beginner in this and I don't seem to find a solution for my scenario. Thanks

Comment: Why are you working with iframes. They come with so many limitations and gotcha's. Just put the code you want to manipulate with(form, buttons, whatever) in the modal. Then when the submit is pressed send the data manipulated as json to your application.

Comment: I did remove the iframe as you said but the problem is, just the close button works and the save does not. Any idea why this happens? normally when the save is clicked, it returns a page with all the information inserted. Thats how it works on the main page. but does not work when I click on the save in my second app

Comment: You need to handle the response from the website in your success handler. The posted json responds with something, you can analyze the response in the network tab of your developer view(F12) and then have your success handler act accordingly by filling containers with the correct response. something like `$.post('foobarbaz', {name:$('.namefield').val()}).done(function(data) {$('#response_container').html(data);$('document).trigger('bindMyEvents');});` where you have bound an event handler previously to bind event handlers to new buttons/elements you have

Comment: so If i understood you correctly, this should be in done in the second app? this is just a basic implementation that i want. do you think this might work if it is some data that has to be stored in a database? will that be feasible  from the second app?

Comment: Without knowing the exact setup I can only offer generic advice, but the normal flow is: Javascript request(client) to fetch new features from controller(server). Controller returns new features. Javascript renders new features by inserting the html somewhere. Javascript binds relevant event handlers.  New element does it things and sends new data to the controller via the bound event handlers. The response dictates if the elements are unbound/removed  or whatever happens new. Take a read at https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/foundation for the javascript side, it explains it pretty well

Comment: thank you for your time. I will take a look